# ODI 11g Interface SQL Data to Multiple Flat Files

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

Is it possible to create an ODI interface that creates multiple flat files based off unique records in a SQL table? There is plenty of information out there regarding how to interface multiple flat files into one SQL datastore - but is it possible the other way around?

Not sure we can tell the interface to create dynamic models based off when certain SQL data primary key data value change for example on a given table? So 600 records with 600 different data points at the PK column corresponding to 600 different rows creates 600 flat files?

Just typing this makes me think the answer is a FIRM NO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it.
Minimal steps with minimal informations:

1. Create a Package;
2. Create a loop in the package (For i = 0; i

   Inside the loop you will setup the name of the file that will be generate (variable);

   Still inside the loop, setup the filter that is used into the interface (variable);

   Still inside the loop, run the interface.

Additional setup.
For the interface you will need two models:

1. for the source
2. for the target

In the model of the target (Technology File) you will need to setup the name of the file. Instead a static name, you will put a project/global variable. That variable you will setup during the loop. So, each time you will loop, you will have a different name.

I tried to be clear and short in the same time. I can expand my explication and give you an example.
If I didn't understood well, please tell me.